# Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef`) while rendering a different component (`Parent`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Parent`,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two different setStates in parent component

```
 const [ isVisible, setIsVisible ] = useState(false);
 const [ validImagePath, setValidImagePath ] = useState(null);
```

also has handle functions in parent

```
const handleVisibility = bool => setIsVisible(true);
const handleImagePath = path => setImagePath(path);
```

that parent has two child components

```
<Child1 handleVisibility={handleVisibility} isVisible={isVisible}/> 
<Child2 validImagePath={validImagePath} handleVisibility={handleVisibility} isVisible={isVisible} />
```

When parent component is rendered then  is visible and onClick it sets a state that it renders <Child 2/>. Everything works fine but I get this warning:
***Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef`) while rendering a different component (`Parent`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Parent`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render.***

Please help in resolving this warning.

Comment: Did you follow the advice that the warning offered?

Comment: Yeah I tried, I couldn't understand what the problem is exactly